# Form that has multiple tbody and multiple hidden fields with same name sends only the last hidden field in the form

Tags: php, html

This form has multiple tbody in one form.
Each tbody contains "hidden" field with "unique" value.
However, when this form is sent, it only sends the last "pouzivatel_id" value.

e.g.

I want to execute "pouzivatel_id"=4, but the form sends "pouzivatel_id"="1"

**How would I fix this without using multiple forms?**

```
<form method="post" action="lib/action/admin.post.php">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Osobné číslo</th>
            <th>Prezývka</th>
            <th>Meno</th>
            <th>Priezvisko</th>
            <th>Operácie</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>00000000004</td>
            <td>user4</td>
            <td>user</td>
            <td>user</td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="pouzivatel_id" value="4"/>
                <button type="submit" name="ziadatel-schvalit" class="tlacidlo zelena">Schváliť</button>
                <button type="submit" name="ziadatel-zmazat" class="tlacidlo cervena">Zamietnuť</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>00000000003</td>
            <td>user3</td>
            <td>user</td>
            <td>user</td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="pouzivatel_id" value="3"/>
                <button type="submit" name="ziadatel-schvalit" class="tlacidlo zelena">Schváliť</button>
                <button type="submit" name="ziadatel-zmazat" class="tlacidlo cervena">Zamietnuť</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>00000000002</td>
            <td>user2</td>
            <td>user</td>
            <td>user</td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="pouzivatel_id" value="2"/>
                <button type="submit" name="ziadatel-schvalit" class="tlacidlo zelena">Schváliť</button>
                <button type="submit" name="ziadatel-zmazat" class="tlacidlo cervena">Zamietnuť</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>00000000001</td>
            <td>user1</td>
            <td>user</td>
            <td>user</td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="pouzivatel_id" value="1"/>
                <button type="submit" name="ziadatel-schvalit" class="tlacidlo zelena">Schváliť</button>
                <button type="submit" name="ziadatel-zmazat" class="tlacidlo cervena">Zamietnuť</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use different form for each set.

Comment: @Sushil: Did you even read the question?

Comment: @ChrisPeters. as far as I know form sent only one key value pair if multiple form fields with same key(name) found.

Comment: @Sushil Maybe I could count the number of total hidden fields and assign a generated number to them, but I don't see that working when I would want to match the value with the generated number

Comment: @user1176253 why don't you want to use multiple forms?

Comment: @JanDvorak I would have to tamper with styling (css) again, oh the horrors :P

Answer (score 1):

You could use a different name for every submit button. If a submit button is pressed, only this submit button is sent to your PHP script. In your PHP script you check which button was pressed.

Example HTML code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="pouzivatel_id[]" value="2"/>
<button type="submit" name="ziadatel-schvalit_2" class="tlacidlo zelena">Schváliť</button>
<button type="submit" name="ziadatel-zmazat_2" class="tlacidlo cervena">Zamietnuť</button>
<input type="hidden" name="pouzivatel_id[]" value="1"/>
<button type="submit" name="ziadatel-schvalit_1" class="tlacidlo zelena">Schváliť</button>
<button type="submit" name="ziadatel-zmazat_1" class="tlacidlo cervena">Zamietnuť</button>
```

Example PHP code:

```
<?PHP
foreach($_POST['pouzivatel_id'] as $id)
{
    if(isset($_POST['ziadatel-schvalit_' . $id]))
    {
        //Schváliť
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['ziadatel-zmazat_' . $id]))
    {
        //Zamietnuť
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I've added an example. Note that I used brackets for your hidden input fields. These fields are accessible in PHP as an array.